# disabled checkboxes get enabled radomly after recycling view through the adapter in android app

Tags: android

i have the following problem. i have set three checkboxes in my app in a way so when i check one of them the other two get disabled. the problem is that when i scroll up or down namely when the views get recycled some of the disabled checkboxes get enabled which of course i dont want to happen. could you please help me to solve that problem?

the code in the adapter is this :

```
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position1, View convertView1, ViewGroup parent1) {

        View listItemView1 = convertView1;

        if (listItemView1 == null) {
            listItemView1 = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item1, parent1, false);
        }

        final ColorQuiz currentColorQuiz = getItem(position1);

        TextView questionTextView = (TextView) listItemView1.findViewById(question_text_view);
        questionTextView.setText(currentColorQuiz.getQuestionHeader());

        final CheckBox box1 = (CheckBox) listItemView1.findViewById(R.id.check_Box_view1);
        box1.setText(currentColorQuiz.getCheckBoxTextA());

        final CheckBox box2 = (CheckBox) listItemView1.findViewById(R.id.check_Box_view2);
        box2.setText(currentColorQuiz.getCheckBoxTextB());

        final CheckBox box3 = (CheckBox) listItemView1.findViewById(R.id.check_Box_view3);
        box3.setText(currentColorQuiz.getCheckBoxTextC());


        box1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                if (box1.isChecked() ) {
                    thesisA[position1]=true;
                    box2.setEnabled(false);
                    box3.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                    thesisA[position1]=false;
                    box2.setEnabled(true);
                    box3.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                int getPositionA = (Integer) compoundButton.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                colorQuizs.get(getPositionA).setSelectedA(compoundButton.isChecked());


            }
        });
        box1.setTag(position1);
        box1.setChecked(colorQuizs.get(position1).isSelectedA());
```

.
.
.
and continues the same way with the next two checkboxes (box2, box3).

Answer (score 1):

maybe while you calling `box1.setChecked` then one of the *old* listeners is called and it is causing problems (as it still has old tag, and propably setting wrong data to your model ).

Try to add at the beggining to make sure that something wrong does not happen:

```
    box1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    box2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    box3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
```

This will tell you if not calling callback while property does not change is reason of this problem:

```
    box1.setChecked(!colorQuizs.get(position1).isSelectedA()); 
    box1.setChecked(colorQuizs.get(position1).isSelectedA());
```

Comment: If you call  setChecked (true) and it is already checked then the callback will not be called, so you should update your model also when you setting this property.

Comment: I mean this line `box1.setChecked(colorQuizs.get(position1).isSelectedA());` if it was checked for example becouse in last item it was checked and it is being reused then callback will not be called as nothing has changed.